# How to show labels of overlapping points in the same layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

If there are 2 points on top of each other in QGIS, only one of them will be labeled

How to make it so that both (or more) points show a label?

Comment: In `Layer > Properties > Labels`, try setting the *Placement* to `Around point` and enable the *Rendering* setting `Show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels)`.

Comment: Note that the above method is only really useful for a small number of overlapping points...

Comment: This doesn't appear to work very well in QGIS 3. I have 4 labels and they overlap.

Comment: When following the steps described by @Joseph, in PLACEMENT, try changing the DISTANCE parameter. Sometimes if the DISTANCE is 0, only one label will show. Increasing to 5 or 10 pixels, the other labels begin to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried to use the rule-based labelling? Doing so, you will be able to define a different position for each label. So you have to build the proper rule for every entity/point.

To do that, once you are on the Layer Properties > Label, you have to click the green cross button at the bottom of the window, give a name to the rule (Description), define the appropriate filter ("name" = 'point 1'), and then click on Placement tab, option Offset from centroid and adjusting the parameters in order to place your label (quadrant + Offset XY). Once done, click and Ok and you should repeat the process defining a new rule for the second point.

Comment: "So you have to build the proper rule for every entity/point." -> Which is not something realistically feasible for a dataset with over 1,500 features and growing every day

Answer (score 1):

The layer that is "on top" is the one that takes priority, so the label belonging to that layer will be shown. If you have overlapping geometries with individual labels, go to the layer settings and select layer clusters as display mode. In my German version of QGIS, this is called "Punkthäufung" or "Punktverdrängung". The label of each feature can then be displayed on your map.

[image]